# pset4 cs50 reflect eroor

Tags: c, cs50

This program reflects the image correctly:

```
void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    int wide=round(width/2);
    for(int i=0;i<height;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<=wide;j++){
            RGBTRIPLE k=image[i][j];
            image[i][j]=image[i][(width-j-1)];
            image[i][width-j]=k;
            
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

But when I run check50 on this it gives following error :

```
:( reflect correctly filters 1x2 image
    expected "0 0 255\n255 0...", not "0 0 255\n0 0 2..."
:( reflect correctly filters 1x3 image
    expected "0 0 255\n0 255...", not "0 0 255\n0 255..."
:) reflect correctly filters image that is its own mirror image
:( reflect correctly filters 3x3 image
    expected "70 80 90\n40 5...", not "70 80 90\n40 5..."
:( reflect correctly filters 4x4 image
    expected "100 110 120\n7...", not "100 110 120\n7..."
:( blur correctly filters middle pixel
    expected "127 140 149\n", not "120 140 150\n"
```

Not sure what is the reason.

Comment: If check50 is giving you errors then it does not reflect the image correctly. No need to round, and the condition should be `<` in the second for loop.

Comment: I've tested it is reflecting image correctly.but what is wrong with my code

Comment: There's two options, your code is not correct or check50 is broken. These don't match either: `image[i][j]=image[i][(width-j-1)];` and `image[i][width-j]=k;` You're missing a `-1` in the second.

Comment: How did you test? Did you test a 1x2 image which is NOT its own mirror image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code:

```
RGBTRIPLE k=image[i][j];
image[i][j]=image[i][(width-j-1)];
image[i][width-j]=k;
```

`image[i][width-j]` is wrong; it is not the pixel that was just loaded to be swapped with `image[i][j]`. It should be `image[i][width-1-j]`.